# How to use Dependency Injection in class?

Tags: php

I have custom class with DI `ImapClient $imapClient`:

```
class MailBoxCleaner
{
  public function __construct(ImapClient $imapClient)
  {
  }
}
```

And there is an facade class:

```
class ImapConnection {

  public function __construct()
  {
     return new ImapClient();
  }
}
```

I tried to use this like:

```
$MailBoxCleaner = new MailBoxCleaner(new ImapConnection());
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you be more clear with letting us know what isn't working and what exactly are you expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor never return any data.

You have to create a getter method that return the instance of your ImapClient class, so you inject it in the other class.

Based on your code :

```
class ImapConnection {
  private $imapClient = null;

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->imapClient = new ImapClient();
  }

  public function getImapClient(){
    return $this->imapClient;
  }
}
```

You can inject :

```
$idObj = new ImapConnection(); // Instanciation

$MailBoxCleaner = new MailBoxCleaner($idObj->get());
```

You also can use a "pattern" :

```
class ImapConnection {
  private $instance = null;
  private $imapClient = null;

  private function __construct()
  {
     $this->imapClient = new ImapClient();
  }

  public static function getImapClient(){
    if(is_null($this->instance){
        $this->instance = new ImapConnection();
    }
    return $this->instance->get();
  }


  private function get(){
    return $this->imapClient;
  }
}
```

Then, you can use in your code :

```
$MailBoxCleaner = new MailBoxCleaner(ImapConnection::getImapClient());
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer by an example?

Comment: Why do you have two `getImapClient()`?

Comment: Just an error with pasting the code... the second one should be "get()" and in the "getImapClient()" return $this->instance->get().
I modify the answer

Comment: Why you can not return $this->imapClient directly in `getImapClient()`?

Comment: You can... Using a getter is not required